# Spring Batch : Execution order for multiple JobExecutionListener instances for a single job

Tags: java, spring-batch, listener, order-of-execution

Given a *Spring Batch* job that has a list of `JobExecutionListener` instances configured for it, what is the execution order for each of the listeners. Example :

```
<job id="myJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">

        <batch:listeners>
            <batch:listener ref="myJobExecutionListener1" />
            <batch:listener ref="myJobExecutionListener2" />
            <batch:listener ref="myJobExecutionListener3" />
            <batch:listener ref="myJobExecutionListener4" />                
        </batch:listeners>

       <!-- job config continues -->
</job>
```

In the above example, **is there a guarentee that the listeners will be executed in the order of configuraiton or will the listeners be executed in a random order**. I tried looking through the *Spring Batch* reference documentation but I could not find this documented as far as my research goes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Listeners will be executed in their declaration order. In your example, they will be called in the following sequence:

```
myJobExecutionListener1.beforeJob
myJobExecutionListener2.beforeJob
myJobExecutionListener3.beforeJob
myJobExecutionListener4.beforeJob

// .. job output

myJobExecutionListener4.afterJob
myJobExecutionListener3.afterJob
myJobExecutionListener2.afterJob
myJobExecutionListener1.afterJob
```

Comment: @MohmoudBenHassine Thanks for answering yet another question from Spring Batch. Is this behavior documented somewhere to ensure that we are not relying on some undocumented behavior?

Comment: Yes, please check the javadoc of [CompositeJobExecutionListener](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/listener/CompositeJobExecutionListener.html).

Comment: I see. When we use a list of listeners, *Spring Batch* internally uses a `CompositeJobExecutionListener`. Still, I feel the behavior that listeners will always be executed in sequence is not directly documented anywhere. One has to know that a `CompositeJobExecutionListener` is used internally to confirm this.

Comment: Please open an issue on [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/projects/BATCH) with a link to this SO thread and we will update the docs accordingly.

Comment: I have never really raised a JIRA before for an open source project. Sounds exciting. Will do it soon.